# Doubt regarding fluid flow

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Suppose a container is filled with water, then pressure at bottom is more than pressure at the top so why doesn’t water starts flowing from bottom to the top?
If I consider a fluid element than the net force on it is zero, so I think that’s why water is not flowing from bottom to the top. Am I correct? And is there any better way to explain this?

Comment: The force produced by pressure difference is balanced by the force of gravity, gravity is the reason the pressure difference exist.

Comment: The pressure at the bottom is supporting the weight of the water above.  So the net force on the water is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is a greater pressure at the bottom than at the top, the fluid in the container is held down due to gravitational force meaning there cannot be a flow in the upward direction.

Gravity and forces due to the inner surfaces of the container keep the entire fluid in hydrostatic equilibrium.